# create hourly interval and loop through to get value_counts python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with datetimeindex from 2019-04-25 15:00:00 until 2019-04-26 15:00:00

for each hour I want to find df["mode"].value_counts() to see how many mode counts there are each hour.

so between_time("08:00", "08:02"), between_time("09:00", "09:02"),between_time("10:00", "10:02"), and so on...

my dataframe looks something like:

```
                        serial_number     mode
gps_updated_at

2019-04-26 15:01:00       A               standby
2019-04-26 15:02:00       A               standby
2019-04-26 15:02:00       B               standby
2019-04-26 15:02:00       B               good
2019-04-26 16:00:00       B               good
2019-04-26 16:01:00       C               bad
```

so for each hour I want to get (15:00:00)

```
standby  3
good     1
```

and 16:00:00

```
good      1
bad       1
```

How can I make an efficient for loop to increment by an hour.

Comment: is `gps_updated_at` your index?

Comment: @Erfan Yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GroupBy` with [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html), the reason I used `Grouper`, is because it keeps your `date` intact.

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='gps_updated_at', freq='H'))['mode'].value_counts()
```

**Output**

```
gps_updated_at       mode   
2019-04-26 15:00:00  standby    3
                     good       1
2019-04-26 16:00:00  bad        1
                     good       1
Name: mode, dtype: int64
```

If you want to return a dataframe, use `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='gps_updated_at', freq='H'))['mode'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
```

**Output**

```
       gps_updated_at     mode  count
0 2019-04-26 15:00:00  standby      3
1 2019-04-26 15:00:00     good      1
2 2019-04-26 16:00:00      bad      1
3 2019-04-26 16:00:00     good      1
```

Comment: this is very good in a sense that I get to keep all datetime. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.hour.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
s = df.groupby(df.index.hour)['mode'].value_counts()
print (s)
gps_updated_at  mode   
15              standby    3
                good       1
16              bad        1
                good       1
Name: mode, dtype: int64

print (s[15])
mode
standby    3
good       1
Name: mode, dtype: int64

print (s[16])
mode
bad     1
good    1
Name: mode, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.index.hour)['mode'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
   gps_updated_at     mode  count
0              15  standby      3
1              15     good      1
2              16      bad      1
3              16     good      1
```

Or convert minutes and seconds to `0` by [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
s = df.groupby(df.index.floor('H').strftime('%H:%M:%S'))['mode'].value_counts()
print (s)
          mode   
15:00:00  standby    3
          good       1
16:00:00  bad        1
          good       1
Name: mode, dtype: int64

print (s['15:00:00'])
mode
standby    3
good       1
Name: mode, dtype: int64

print (s['16:00:00'])
mode
bad     1
good    1
Name: mode, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df2 = df.groupby(df.index.floor('H').strftime('%H:%M:%S').rename('hour'))['mode'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
print (df2)
       hour     mode  count
0  15:00:00  standby      3
1  15:00:00     good      1
2  16:00:00      bad      1
3  16:00:00     good      1
```